# For ideals $I=(8)$ and $J=(5+5i)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, what are $IJ$, $I+J$ and $I\cap J$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $I=(8)$ and $J=(5+5i)$ be ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

How do I find $x,y,z\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$ such that:
$IJ=(x)$,
$I+J=(y)$,
$I\cap J=(z)$?

Is it correct that $y=13+5i$ and $x=40+40i$?

Comment: Your answer for $IJ$ looks correct.  For the other two, recall that in a PID, $(a) + (b) = (\gcd(a,b))$ and $(a) \cap (b) = (\text{lcm}(a,b))$.  So if you factor $8$ and $5 + 5i$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, you should be able to find the answer.

Comment: @SpamIAm I have $8=4(1+i)(1-i)$ and $5+5i=5(1+i)$, so the gcd is $1+i$, what is the lcm?

Comment: By factor, I meant factor into primes.  $5$ is not prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and neither is $4$ ($4$ isn't even prime  in $\mathbb{Z}$!).  Also note that $1+i$ and $1-i$ are associate, since $1-i = -i(1+i)$ and $-i$ is a unit.

Comment: @SpamIAm Sorry thats right!

Comment: @SpamIAm So $8=i(1+i)^6$ and $5+5i=(2+i)(2-i)(1+i)$?

Comment: Looks good!  Now you can easily solve the last two, right?

Comment: @SpamIAm Yes! Thanks for the help, if you want you can make an answer out of this, so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute $IJ$, note that if $I = (x_1, \ldots, x_m)$ and $J = (y_1, \ldots, y_n)$, one can show that
$$
IJ = (x_1, \ldots, x_m)(y_1, \ldots, y_n) = (x_i y_j : 1 \leq i \leq m, 1 \leq j \leq n),
$$
i.e., the product of the ideals is generated by all products of their generators.

Recall that in a PID we have $(a) + (b) = (\gcd(a,b))$ and $(a) \cap (b) = (\text{lcm}(a,b))$.  Since $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a PID, it suffices to determine the prime factorization of $8$ and $5 + 5i$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.  Since
$$
2 = (1 + i)(1 - i) = (1+i) (-i)(i + 1) = -i (1 + i)^2
$$
then $8 = 2^3 = i(1+i)^6$.  Note that
$$
5 + 5i = 5(1+i) = (2+i)(2-i)(1+i) \, .
$$
(One can show that these factors are indeed prime since their norms are prime, where $N: \mathbb{Z}[i] \to \mathbb{Z}$ is the multiplicative norm map $N(a+bi) = a^2 + b^2$.)  Then $\gcd(8, 5 + 5i) = 1+i$ and
$$
\text{lcm}(8, 5+5i) = \frac{8(5+5i)}{\gcd(8,5+5i)} = \frac{8(5+5i)}{1+i} = 8 \cdot 5 = 40 \, .
$$